# Most efficient way to concatenate large numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on a data generator for a machine learning model that takes video frames as input. The videos (along with the needed labels) are stored as hdf5 files, 11 in total each containing a separate video. The total size of the frames is around 80GB and I have 60GB of available memory but I have more than enough swap allocated.

I want the generation process to be as fast as possible so it doesn't become a bottleneck for training. For this purpose I am loading the entire data in memory first before sampling at each epoch. I am extracting the numpy arrays from each hdf5 file, appending it to a list, then concatenate the contents of the list into a large numpy array. The sampling process is indeed a lot faster than sampling from the hdf5 files since they don't load the content in memory.

My problem is with the initial allocation of data. Since I am concatenating a list that contains numpy arrays that add up to around 80GB in size, `np.concatenate` allocates another 80GB to move the data to, since it is not 'in-place'. It is still able to allocate the required space but it takes a considerable amount of time to allocate then copy the data to the new space, which becomes a bottleneck each time you start a new training session.

Is there a better way to concatenate a list of large numpy arrays (7~8GB each) without reallocating memory if possible. Or would you go about loading the data in another way. I am looking for the fastest way that ensure that sampling will not be a bottleneck for training while keeping the time needed to load the data to a minimum.

One more thing, I was wondering if saving the numpy array at the end and loading it using `np.load` will be faster than using the hdf5 format or not, taking into account the large size of the data.

Comment: An array must have contiguous memory, so you can't make one array from many without that kind of copy.  `tensorflow` and similar machine-learning packages can work with 'batches'.  Depending on what you need to do with the arrays, something like that may be faster than making one large array.

Comment: @hpaulj Ultimately, I would want to random sample the entire data for each batch, that's why pre-loading the entire data at first is faster at training time. I don't think an array of this size could be contiguous so it might not be possible as you said. Just wondering if there may be a better approach.